# Rails circular and dynamic nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, simple-form, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I'm trying to create a 'blog' example with a **circular and dynamic nested form**, but I can't make it work, it just keeps loading forever and I need to kill the server in order to stop it.

A blog has comments, and a comment has comments. That's all.

Please help me :)

I'm using:

- rails (5.1.6)
- activerecord (5.1.6)
- simple_form (3.5.1)
- cocoon (1.2.11)
- jquery-rails (4.3.1)
- haml (5.0.4)

*blog.rb*

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  validates :message, presence: true

  has_many :comments, inverse_of: :blog

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments,
    allow_destroy: true,
    reject_if: ->(attributes) {attributes[:text].blank?}
end
```

*comment.rb*

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :blog, inverse_of: :comments, optional: true
  belongs_to :comment, optional: true
  has_many :comments, inverse_of: :comment

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments,
    allow_destroy: true,
    reject_if: ->(attributes) {attributes[:text].blank?}
end
```

*form.html.haml*

```
= simple_form_for blog do |f|
  = f.input :message

  .comments
    = f.simple_fields_for :comments do |comment|
      = render 'comment_fields', f: comment

  = link_to_add_association 'Add', f, :comments, data: {association_insertion_node: '.comments', association_insertion_method: :append}

  = f.button :submit
```

*_comment_fields.html.haml*

```
.nested-fields.ml-3
  = link_to_remove_association 'Remove', f

  = f.input :text

  = f.simple_fields_for :comments do |sub_comment|
    = render 'comment_fields', f: sub_comment

= link_to_add_association 'Add', f, :comments, data: {association_insertion_node: '.comments', association_insertion_method: :append}
```

I also tried with the [Railscasts example](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised), and it didn't work because the link_to_add_fields helper loads the comment_fields file and it has the link_to_add_fields inside.

Comment: I'm not so sure you should even be using nested attributes here. Rather just treat them as two separate resources with a standard CRUD controller for each. I don't really see why you would need to create a blog post and comments in the same request or a comment and replies in the same request.

Comment: Yes, you are right it's just an example, sorry. The real project has categories with categories inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... [it's an issue with the cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/issues/408). I found a possible (and dirty) solution, if I limit the nesting, it works.

```
.nested-fields.ml-3
  = f.input :text

  - index ||= 0
  - index += 1
  - if index < 10
    = link_to_add_association 'Add', f, :comments, data: {association_insertion_method: :append}, render_options: {locals: {index: index}}

  = link_to_remove_association 'Remove', f

  = f.simple_fields_for :comments do |sub_comment|
    = render 'comment_fields', f: sub_comment
```

Comment: True, cocoon or any server-based nested-fields handler in rails will have this problem. When rendering the `link_to_add_association` we pre-render the form for the nested item to be inserted, containing the same `link_to_add_association` again, which will render ... You get the drift. If you truly need dynamic unlimited deep nested categories, which might be the case, then you will have to take the ajax/xhr route. A possible cleaner solution to limit the nesting: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon-self_join-form/blob/master/app/views/employees/_employee_fields.html.erb

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, but i.e. if you have 10 Employees, you will render 50 forms and takes a lot of time to load.

Comment: Cocoon allows to pre-render everything on the server, so you do not have to use ajax/xhr. But pre-rendering on the server takes time, definitely when the form is self-referential as in your case. There are a lot of advantages to using a more ad-hoc solution using ajax/xhr. It also depends on the UI: do you need to have a single form with all the nested data (1 commit) or not.